# How to customize Collections.sort() to sort strings in order of their numerical prefix

Tags: java, sorting

I have a `List<String>` containing below values:

> [1h, 0h, 2h, 10h, 4h, 9h, 3h, 7h, 8h, 6h, 5h]

When I sort it using `Collections.sort()`, the order becomes:

> [0h, 10h, 1h, 2h, 3h, 4h, 5h, 6h, 7h, 8h, 9h]

Instead, it should be:

> [0h, 1h, 2h, 3h, 4h, 5h, 6h, 7h, 8h, 9h, 10h]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add your code as well ?

Comment: `Collections.sort()` gives [01h, 02h, 10h] if  the elements are strings

Comment: Are you trying to sort an `List<String>`? If yes, then something is wrong here, since it **never** would order like you stated. If not, then please tell us what is the class you are trying to sort.

Comment: Collections.sort should be ok for you. Please paste your code

Comment: Thanks... I have edited and added the code, Please advise

Comment: Yes @MiguelKVidal List<String> is being used

Comment: Your code sorts parameter names. Are you sure you don't want to sort parameter values? What is printed when you add System.out.println(list);, before and after the call to Collections.sort()?

Comment: Yes @JBNizet, I need to sort parameter names, before Collection.sort() the output is shuffled and after applying the sort() the order becomes 01h, 10h, 02h... if there are 10 parameters sent (the 10th parameter is named as 10h). Else upto 9 parameters there is no problem i.e the output order for 9 parameters is : 01h, 02h,...,09h

Comment: Post the output, literally. Don't describe it.

Comment: Maybe you are leaving out important information about your problem, as stated by @janos. Please, give us more information and the code that you are using. The only thing I can think of that **maybe** can "missplace values after a sort function", are invisible characters. Use the following code to print every item of your list and tell us the results:
`for(String i : list){
System.out.println("["+i+"] = "+i.length());
}`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, as requested I have updated the question with the output, please advise on that.

Comment: Now it's easy! 0h, 10h 1h is the correct order here!
If it was 01h, then it would be the order you want: 00h, 01h, 10h.
Adjust the name of your parameters, or you can create a customized sorter. Do you know how to sort it?

Comment: Thanks @MiguelKVidal, yes got the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you quoted in your question is normal. If you look at the API description of [`Collection.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) you'll see:

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).

By natural ordering they mean the ordering specified by their `compareTo`-method (the interface `Comparable` only has the method `compareTo`) which tells wether the `this`-object is is greater (return strict positive integer), or are equal (return 0), less(return strict negative integer) than the object passed as an argument in the ordering. To know if an object `a` should get before object `b`, it just calls `a.compareTo(b)`.

- If it's result is strict positive (> 0) the `sort` method will set `a` after `b` in the sorted array.
- If it's result is strict negative (< 0) the `sort` method will set `a` before `b` in the sorted array.
- If it's result is 0 the `sort` method won't change the order they are in.

I would refer to [the API of the `compareTo` method in the `String` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-), it is explained in detail there how strings are ordered and what the method returns.
What it does is just iterating character per character over each string and compare the characters at the same position untill a difference is found. If at that difference, the character of the `this`-string has a higher [Unicode value](http://unicode-table.com/en/), it will return a strict positive integer (the `this` stringer is greater) else it will return a strict negative integer (the `this`-string is lower than the argument). If no difference can be found it will return 0 (the `this`-string and the argument have same "order value").
Now the problem in your case(and for many people who order strings for the first time) is that integers can't be ordered with that Unicode-ordering because it goes character per character. If it has to sort `String s1 = "19"` and `String s2 = "1119"` it will call `s1.compareTo(s2)`. The first difference is at the second character `s1` has `9` and `s2` has `1` at that position. Since **`1` comes before `9` in the Unicode-table** (`1` has value hexadecimal value 31 and `9` has hexadecimal value 39), `s1.compareTo(s2)` will return a strict positive integer (see the link to the API to see which value). Thus **it will put `s2` before `s1` in the sorted array even if `1119 > 19`**!

So now you know why it sorts like that, let's see what solutions we have:

1. [`Map`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm) your array-elements to the decimal value of their begin-part using the [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) method, sort these decimal values and map the resulting sorted arrays back to your original elements. I wouldn't really recommand this solution because of the extra collections and the extra code due to the mapping.
2. Create your own [`Comparator`-object](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/), specify in there how you want your strings to be ordered (for example using the [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) method) and pass it as argument to the [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method. By passing it as an argument, you tell the sort methode to use your `Comparator`-object instead of the classic `compareTo` methode. [This link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/) shows how a `Comparator` is used to sort an array. It's quite the same as using it to sort an arraylist.

Hope it helps!

Good luck